# Is there possibility to two-way-bind ngModel to Map item in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looping to display inputs and would like to bind value of an input to Map<index:number, inputValue: string>() so that I can change appropriate inputValue in my ts file. (Index of for is id of parameter)

```
<div *ngFor="let parameter of parameters; let i = index">
...
<input #myInputValue [(ngModel)]="myDictionary.set(i, setStartingValue(parameter.code))" ...>
<button (click)="setValueOfInput(i, "some value")"
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough. It would be helpful if you can add the ts file code. Or explain further what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.